# How to change mjs_histogram bar color (using metricsgraphics r package)?

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets, metricsgraphicsjs

I can't seem to figure out how to change the color of the histogram created using the metricsgraphics package. I've built a functioning Shiny app that renders a histogram using thecode below:

```
mjs_plot(zedata()$Value, format="count") %>% 
        mjs_histogram(bins = 10) %>%
        mjs_labs(x=input$item, y="Number of VA Medical Centers")
```

I added color = "#d7191c" mjs_plot and mjs_histogram to no avail - I got an unused argument error on both occasions. I couldn't find anything on hrbrmstr's info page http://hrbrmstr.github.io/metricsgraphics/ nor could I find anything in the help manual. It seems using the color option is explained for every graph type other than histograms.

I am not adept at html/javascript and not sure what else to try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to modify the CSS for the classes corresponding to the histogram rectangles (look for the name of the classes in the [original CSS](https://github.com/mozilla/metrics-graphics/blob/master/dist/metricsgraphics.css)).

An easy way to do this is adding the following code into your `UI` definition :

```
tags$head(
  tags$style(HTML("
    .mg-histogram .mg-bar rect {
        fill: <your_color>;
        shape-rendering: auto;
    }

    .mg-histogram .mg-bar rect.active {
        fill: <another_color>;
    }")))
```

There are other ways to add custom CSS, see [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).

Here is a full example:

```
n <- 5
library(metricsgraphics)
library(shiny)

# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .mg-histogram .mg-bar rect {
          fill: #ff00ff;
          shape-rendering: auto;
      }

      .mg-histogram .mg-bar rect.active {
          fill: #00f0f0;
      }"))),
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  metricsgraphicsOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderMetricsgraphics({
    mjs_plot(mtcars$mpg, format="count") %>% 
      mjs_histogram(bins = input$n)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```